# How to determine if Salesforce User Record is Active in a Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, error-messages, user-record

I am trying to build a simple flow and am getting an unexpected error.

**Background:** We have 2 User Lookup fields on Account - Standard Account Owner and custom Account BDR. We also have the similar fields on the related Contact records - Standard Contact Owner and custom Contact BDR

**What we're looking for:** We would like the Contact Owner and Contact BDR to update to the same values as the related Account Owner and Account BDR when a Contact record is updated

**Issue:** We only want this flow to fire if the Account Owner or Account BDR users are Active. To do this, I put in a Decision element right after the Trigger which loos to see if the Account Owner and Account BDR is Active.

*However, I am getting an error that says: "Error element Are_Owners_Active (FlowDecision).
The flow failed to access the value for $Record.Account.Account_BDR__r.IsActive because it hasn't been set or assigned."*

Does anyone here know what I may be doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your decision statement has an 'AND' and not an 'OR'. Is that expected.?